# Unable to use rmw_cyclonedds_cpp with ROS2 Humble under Windows

Tags: ros2, rmw

I'm using ROS2 Humble, installed from binaries. Experiencing some performance issues, I want to try different middleware implementation.

So I simply do:

```
set RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_cyclonedds_cpp
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker
```

It reports

> 1708008610.728686 [0]      35796: selected interface "Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1" is not multicast-capable: disabling multicast`

Then messages are published by the node.

Then I run `ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener`. It reports the same message and does not receive any message from the talker.

Without `RMW_IMPLEMENTATION` set, it works just fine.

Is `rmw_cyclonedds_cpp` supposed to work? Why does it fail here? Is the message reporting `disabling multicast` linked to the fact it does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you must stop the daemon after you set `RMW_IMPLEMENTATION` to be sure it runs with the same implementation as other nodes, so:

```
set RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_cyclonedds_cpp
ros2 daemon stop
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker
```

And then:

```
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener
```

Works just fine.